# Internet is working when browsing, but extremely slow download speed and in-games huge ping

Tags: networking, router, dns, internet

So this has been going on awhile now, its one of those things that for over a year its been on and off. But in the past month, it has been really bad. At the start of when it turned really bad It was when I moved rooms in my house, the route would get that orange light (I'm with sky) telling me something is wrong with it. I would not be able to connect to the internet and when I could, I'd go to play a game and my ping would be around a steady 300 and sometimes shooting up to 1000!

I bought a new TP Link instead of using the USB Wireless thing thinking that was the problem, but now what is happening is: Still very high ping in games non stop (I play League of Legends and it was lagging on Runescape also) I can browse the internet fine (a little bit slow sometimes and sometimes not as much but it will dissconnect me) when I troubleshoot, it either finds nothing or says 'The default gateway is not available     Not Fixed' it is very random it has said other things like it is broken and then soon as I click off I can browse the internet easy, but other times it wont work for a full day.

The things I have tried:

- Flushed DNS Cache
- I had two local area connections and the 2nd one wasn't working at all barely and it was a Hamachi one so i disabled it.
- Changed the DNS to 8.8.8.8 alt 8.8.4.4
- Reset the router to factory settings (suggesting by sky as they said our router had no problems and was working fine)
- Also my download speed and upload speed has always been extremely low (suspiciously low, I'm talking 8 Mb download speed and 0.70 upload speed if I'm lucky, I don't know what sky is promising us because its under my parents and they aren't technical at all and wont listen)
- I should probably mention that we have a lot of devices in the house that all work perfectly even my mams laptop connects fully. (It is not a case of they are taking the internet away since i stay awake until 4am when only my pc and phone are being used and still my internet will be funny)

If you need any other information that might help please feel free to ask, I'm not the most technical person ever but I know a few stuff so just ask! Please help me I have college work to do and  I cant even download programs that I need because they either fail or take about 4 days and then still don't end up working.

Comment: "i dont know what sky is promising us" Well, then, there's little chance of us being able to help, either. Maybe you have exactly what your parents signed up for. Additionally, you forgot to tell us even what type of Internet access you have. Cable modem? Satellite? xDSL? You haven't told us what speeds are available on other computers, or what the difference is between yours and the other computers.

Comment: I've just checked there, we're being promised 15359 kilobit per second downstream. Im connected through a TP Link that one connects into the socket and into my computer, and the other from the socket downstairs into the router.

Comment: Like i said im not extremely technical about all this stuff, and if my mams laptop is connected through a wire, but my phone never has trouble with the internet and obviously thats wireless (no its not using data its definatly using the Wifi) if this helps 'Attached Devices
android-a88dceb953768bd5 Wireless
James-PC Cabled'

Comment: If "sky" refers to the satellite provider Sky Networks you will likely always have higher latency.  This uplink and downlink hops are killer. It's not so noticeable just browsing the internet,  but game play is a different matter.

Comment: To me it sounds like you have some faulty cabling. You stated that it got worse after you moved into a different room. My guess is that cable that goes from the room to wherever, has something wrong with it. Whether it's a poorly terminated end, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can most likely be narrowed down to one or both of
(a) LAN connectivity issues or
(b) Upload issues.
ie, while it is possible its something else, its unlikely to be DNS related.

The first step in solving this problem is checking your level of connectivity - one way to do this would be to get WinMTR or equivalent and run it for a reasonable period of time.  [ You may want to post your results here ].

If there is a lot of latency and/or packet loss on the first hop, then the issue is with your LAN or router (most likely noisy WIFI).  If not, it could be an ISP issue.

My bet would be on a lot of WIFI devices in the area competing for space and killing the spectrum.  You can check this theory if you have an android device by getting WIFI Analyser which will list the AP's and overlapping signal strengths.    If your computer has an ethernet interface, plugging into the router with a cable will eliminate WIFI issues, and most likely give you more bandwidth and lower and more consistent pings.

Comment: When it asks for host what would i put in there? my ip or something else?

Comment: 8.8.8.8 might be suitable - really it can be any domain name or IP address of a site which you know has good connectivity.

Comment: <a href="http://s1024.photobucket.com/user/Hushh-kun/media/Results_zpsjneh3rpi.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y306/Hushh-kun/Results_zpsjneh3rpi.png" border="0" alt="Results photo Results_zpsjneh3rpi.png"/></a>

Comment: After about an hour thats the results i got

Comment: Problem is on your LAN.  Notice how the wrst column for 192.168.0.1 is 1760 - that means it took 1.7 seconds for 56 bytes (or so) of information to go to your router and back.   The variability points towards bad WIFI connectivity.  Are you able to connect your computer up via Ethernet temporarily to confirm that this makes the problem go away ?  (It could be a problem with your router, but this is a lot less likely)

Comment: I can try set my computer up downstairs with the router to test how the Ethernet cable changes things, Once i have done that ill try it out see what changes happen, ill let you know after

Comment: okay, im sorry this is late but my computer just completely stopped letting me use internet not sure why at all. I have now bought a new laptop and the internet in general works fine. HOWEVER for some random reason ive began getting bad ping in games (which is how my computer started out) and now if i plug it into the ethernet cable the ping is fine but the WiFi causes unstable ping. Does this mean that the problem is my Wifi from my router or my laptop?